# Scripting.Dictionary .Add data member not found

Tags: vb6

I am new to visual basic and I am working on vbjson i-e integrating it in already written application(`Visual Basic 6.0`) and in its module JSON.bas there is method to add key and value in dictionary. The problem is compiler always gives error that data member not found.

I am able to see the class libraries and its members from object browser .
script.dictionarylibrary has class with  add member but  dictionary in word library doesn't have it .

I don't know how to resolve this error. here is the code

```
   Set parseObject = New scripting.Dictionary

   parseObject.Add sKey, parseValue(str, Index)
```

Comment: Which data member isn't found?

Comment: it says  data member not found and highlights the  `pasrseObject.Add` so probably `.Add` is not found

Comment: Ok. I suspect that you aren't getting your `parseObject` properly instantiated. That's borne out by the fact that `Scripting.Dictionary` should have a capital S and your code has it in lower case. The object certainly has an `Add` member. Are you familiar with how to set references to object libraries in VB6?

Comment: Sorry my mistake its capital S there and it is working fine when i do seperately Vbjson example code which i downloaded from http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html. 

but when i try to use its classes and modules in my already built vb6 application it starts giving error.
Sorry dear i m not familiar with "how to set references to object libraries in Vb6"  . let me try to search it. thanks

Comment: @BobRodes As far as I know, VB6 was case-insensitive; `New scripting.dictionary` and `new Scripting.Dictionary` are exactly the same. It's more likely that the OP is having reference issues...

Comment: @ferc absolutely so, but my theory was based on the fact that if there were a reference to the `Scripting` component the IDE would have auto-corrected it to `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Waseem, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa261366%28v%3dvs.60%29). The reference you're looking for is "Microsoft Scripting Runtime." If you don't have that reference checked, you can't use the `Scripting` component.